# How to use dill library for object serialization with shelve library

Tags: python, pickle, coroutine, shelve, dill

I'm using `PyMemoize` library to cache coroutine. I decorated the coroutine, but when Python calls it, I get:

```
TypeError: can't pickle coroutine objects
```

This happens because `PyMemoize` internally tries to pickle coroutine and store it inside Redis. For this, it uses `shelve.Shelf`, which in turn uses `pickle`. The problem is that, by unknown reason, `pickle` doesn't support pickling coroutines.

I've tried to pickle coroutines with `dill` and it worked. How do I tell `shelve` to use `dill` as serialization backend?

I've tried to monkey-patch `shelve`, but it didn't work (I don't know why):

```py
import shelve
from dill import Pickler, Unpickler
shelve.Pickler = Pickler
shelve.Unpickler = Unpickler
```

Answer (score 5):

You can save functions with yields, but not generators. From [documentation](https://dill.readthedocs.io/en/latest/): "dill cannot yet pickle these standard types:
frame, **generator**, traceback."

This code is worked (dill version 0.3.0):

```
import shelve
from dill import Pickler, Unpickler
shelve.Pickler = Pickler
shelve.Unpickler = Unpickler
d=shelve.open("shelve.dat")
d['1']=Ellipsis
d.close()
```

But without dill we get "TypeError: can't pickle ellipsis objects":

```
import shelve
d=shelve.open("shelve.dat")
d['1']=Ellipsis
d.close()
```

Comment: For the record, this fix also works when `shelve` is complaining `AttributeError: Can't pickle local object` due to lambdas it's unhappy with. Thanks!