# I need to both resolve an error saving an object with "shelve", and make the code throwing that error more robust in general

Tags: python-3.x

I'm teaching myself Python using a roguelike tutorial. I've hit a bug with saving the game, and I'm trying to figure out how to resolve it.

My save-game code is dirt simple, and looks like this:

```
def save_game(engine: Engine) -> None:
    with shelve.open('savegame', 'n') as data_file:
        data_file['engine'] = engine
```

Then "engine" object has all the game-state info I need. Most of the time, it works great.

However, I've found that the auto-save gets screwed up when it triggers after I use a fireball scroll:

```
AttributeError: Can't pickle local object 'FireballDamageConsumable.get_action.<locals>.<lambda>'
```

Poking around a bit, I gather that I need to somehow get `dill` into the mix. Just doing `import dill` isn't enough.

However! Before I solve THAT problem, I have another problem I'd like to solve first while I still have this bug that lets me see it.

If I quite the game immediately after the failed save, my save file is now corrupted. The auto-load feature won't pick it up (and in the current state of the game, that means I have to delete the save file manually). An auto-save that periodically corrupts its own save file seems like a much more significant problem.

So, my question is really a two-parter:

1. How to I refactor my `save_game` method to be smarter? How do I prevent it from corrupting the file if something goes wrong? Should I pre-`pickle` the `engine` object, and only do `shelve.open` if that doesn't throw any errors? Is there a simple way for me to create a backup file from the old data and then revert to it if something goes awry? (**Edit:** Think I might have this part working.)
2. Once Part 1 is resolved, is there a way for me to tweak my call to `shelve` so that it doesn't get confused by lambdas? Do I just need to by hyper-vigilant any time a lambda shows up in my code and make sure it gets omitted from the state I'm trying to save? Are there any other "gotchas" I need to be aware of that would make this kind of brute force "Just save the entire game state" approach a bad idea?

Thanks in advance for any guidance anyone can offer.

**Edit:**
I did put together some code for backing up the save file that seems to do the job. I'm tossing it in here just in case someone wants to point me towards some common/built-in Python utility that does all this work for me. Failing that, this seems to prevent the autosave from corrupting its own file. Now I just have to figure out why it was trying to corrupt the file in the first place.

```
SAVE_FILE_BASE = 'savegame'
SAVE_FILE_LIST = [SAVE_FILE_BASE + '.dat', SAVE_FILE_BASE + '.dir', SAVE_FILE_BASE + '.bak']


def save_game(engine: Engine) -> None:
    # Make a copy of the old save file (if it exists) just in case this one gets janked.
    
    backup()
    
    try:
        with shelve.open(SAVE_FILE_BASE, 'n') as data_file:
            data_file['engine'] = engine
        purge_backups()
        data_file.close()
    except Exception:
        data_file.close()
        traceback.print_exc()
        restore_backups()

def backup() -> None:
    [cautious_copy(file, file + '.bak') for file in SAVE_FILE_LIST] 

def restore_backups() -> None:
    [cautious_move(file + '.bak', file) for file in SAVE_FILE_LIST]
    
def purge_backups() -> None:
    [cautious_remove(file + '.bak') for file in SAVE_FILE_LIST]
        
def cautious_copy(src: str, dest: str) -> None:
    if os.path.isfile(src):
        copy2(src, dest)
        
def cautious_move(src: str, dest: str) -> None:
    if os.path.isfile(src):
        move(src, dest)
        
def cautious_remove(file: str) -> None:
    if os.path.isfile(file):
        os.remove(file)
```

Answer (score 0):

Ah-ha! Looks like this question fixes my problem:

[How to use dill library for object serialization with shelve library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52927236/how-to-use-dill-library-for-object-serialization-with-shelve-library)

Plugging this into the import statements does the trick:

```
from dill import Pickler, Unpickler
shelve.Pickler = Pickler
shelve.Unpickler = Unpickler
```